# how to change the function name in the url using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to change the function name in the url, i searched for this a lot but unable to find any solution, can any one help me out what should  i do 
consider for example i have a url like

`http://localhost/codeIgniter_try/index.php/Blog/blogvieww` ,

so here "Blog" is the controller name and "blogvieww" is the function name so if i want to change the function name from "blogvieww" to "blogvieww_all" what can i do?

Blog.php

```
   <?php  
        defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  

        class Blog extends CI_Controller {  

            public function index()  
            {  
                $this->load->view('blogview');  
            }

            public function blogvieww()  
            {  
                $this->load->view('blogvieww');  
            }
        }  
    ?>
```

blogview.php

```
    <html>
        <head>
                <title>My Blog</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome to my 1st Blog!</h1>
            </div>    
        </body>
    </html>
```

blogvieww.php

```
    <html>
        <head>
                <title>My Blog</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome to my 2nd Blog!</h1>
            </div>

            <div>
                <h1>Welcome to my 3rd Blog!</h1>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This will help. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: i searched here but did not understood sir can u please explain me how can i achive my desired result

Comment: change your route like this `$route['Blog/blogvieww_all'] = 'Blog/blogvieww';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Add the below line of code in your `route.php`*

```
$route['Blog/blogvieww_all'] = 'Blog/blogvieww';
```

*Your anchor should be like this :*

```
<a href=<?=site_url('Blog/blogvieww_all');?>
```

Comment: happy coding once again Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can set it through `routes` of CodeIgniter.

Your path for `routes` will be **application/config/routes.php**

See this below may help.

```
$route['Blog/blogvieww_all'] = 'Blog/blogvieww';
```

For more detail: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

1) You can use URI routes. In routes.php, You can specify like below:

`$route['Blog/blogvieww_all'] = 'Blog/blogvieww';`

[Check here for more info.](http://%20Check%20here%20(https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html))

2) Write same function again in controller with the name of 'blogvieww_all' .

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your controller:

```
   public function blogvieww()  
        {  
            $this->load->view('blogvieww');  
        }
```

to

```
   public function blogviewW_all()  
        {  
            $this->load->view('blogvieww');  
        }
```

You just need to change the name of the function in your controller, to the name you want to display on ur url.

Or

As Pradeep has commented, you can change to routing also. But the best way is to change the function name, unless it is being referenced or called from somewhere else.

Comment: sir i don want to change the function name in controller i want to change the function anme only in url using routes

Comment: LIke this: $route['Blog/blogvieww_all'] = 'Blog/blogvieww';